# Undefined variable error comming at Update in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, updates

Here my code , when I am doing update code I am getting same message every time -"Undefined variable" . Please help me to find the problem . I dont able to solve the problem for last 2days.

**Error Message --**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: department

Filename: medical_diagnosis/test_department_form.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:

File: /home/qsystems/public_html/hospital/application/views/medical_diagnosis/test_department_form.php
Line: 17
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/qsystems/public_html/hospital/application/controllers/medical_diagnosis/Test_department.php
Line: 26
Function: view

File: /home/qsystems/public_html/hospital/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I am sharing my view , controller and Model .

**View**

Here is my View file `test_department_form.php`

```html
<div class="row">
    <!--  form area -->
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div  class="panel panel-default thumbnail">
 
            <div class="panel-heading no-print">
                <div class="btn-group"> 
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url("medical_diagnosis/test_department") ?>"> <i class="fa fa-list"></i>  <?php echo display('medical_diagnosis_test_dept_lst') ?> </a>  
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="panel-body panel-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">

                        <?php echo form_open('medical_diagnosis/test_department/create','class="form-inner"') ?>
                         <?php echo form_hidden('id',$department->id) ?>
                           
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label"><?php echo display('department_name') ?> <i class="text-danger">*</i></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-9">
                                    <input name="name"  type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="<?php echo display('department_name') ?>" value="<?php echo $department->name ?>"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <!--Radio-->
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3"><?php echo display('status') ?></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-9"> 
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked><?php echo display('active') ?></label>
                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="status" value="0"><?php echo display('inactive') ?></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="ui buttons">
                                        <button type="reset" class="ui button"><?php echo display('reset') ?></button>
                                        <div class="or"></div>
                                        <button class="ui positive button"><?php echo display('save') ?></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php echo form_close() ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Controller**

Here is my Controllerfile `Test_department.php`

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test_department extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  
  $this->load->model(array(
     'medical_diagnosis/test_department_model'
      ));
  
  if ($this->session->userdata('isLogIn') == false 
   || $this->session->userdata('user_role') != 1 
  ) 
  redirect('login'); 

 }

 public function index()
 {
  $data['title'] = display('medical_diagnosis_test_dept');
  #-------------------------------#
  $data['departments'] = $this->test_department_model->read();
  $data['content'] = $this->load->view('medical_diagnosis/test_department_form',$data,true);
  $this->load->view('layout/main_wrapper',$data);
 }
 public function create() 
 {

  $data['title'] = display('medical_diagnosis_test_dept_add');
  #-------------------------------#
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', display('department_name') ,'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', display('status') ,'required');
  #-------------------------------#
  $data['department'] = (object)$postData = [
   'id'    => $this->input->post('id',true),
   'name'     => $this->input->post('name',true),
   'status'      => $this->input->post('status',true)
  ]; 
  #-------------------------------#
  if ($this->form_validation->run() === true) {

   #if empty $dprt_id then insert data
   if (empty($postData['id'])) {
    if ($this->test_department_model->create($postData)) {
     #set success message
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', display('save_successfully'));
    } else {
     #set exception message
     $this->session->set_flashdata('exception',display('please_try_again'));
    }
    redirect('medical_diagnosis/test_department/create');
   } else {
    if ($this->test_department_model->update($postData)) {
     #set success message
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', display('update_successfully'));
    } else {
     #set exception message
     $this->session->set_flashdata('exception',display('please_try_again'));
    }
    redirect('test_department/edit/'.$postData['id']);
   }

  } else {
   $data['content'] = $this->load->view('medical_diagnosis/test_department_form',$data,true);
   $this->load->view('layout/main_wrapper',$data);
  }

 }

 public function edit($id = null) 
 {
  $data['title'] = display('department_edit');
  #-------------------------------#
  
  

$data['department'] = $this->test_department_model->read_by_id($id);
  $data['content'] = $this->load->view('medical_diagnosis/test_department_form',$data,true);
  $this->load->view('layout/main_wrapper',$data);
 }






}
```

**Model**

Here is my model `Test_department_model.php`

```html
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test_department_model extends CI_Model {
 private $table = 'diagnosis_test_department';

 public function create($data = [])
 {  
  return $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
 }

 public function read()
 {
  return $this->db->select("*")
   ->from($this->table)
   ->order_by('id','desc')
   ->get()
   ->result();
 } 
 public function read_by_id($id = null)
 {
  return $this->db->select("*")
   ->from($this->table)
   ->where('id',$id)
   ->get()
   ->row();
 } 
 public function update($data = [])
 {
  return $this->db->where('id',$data['id'])
   ->update($this->table,$data); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: pls be more precise ,where you getting undefined variable

Comment: error in updation or creation?

Comment: When I am delete the code at view file "<?php echo form_hidden('id',$department->id) ?>"  , then error is not comming at the insert time , Insert is ok , but at the time of data fetch for update then problem is happen ,  "**Message: Undefined variable: department**" ,

I attached the error right now , please see

Comment: can you reply me what I have to do sir ?

Comment: undefined variable means it is not getting data either it is not coming from the database or not properly set to the views pls check these

Comment: But from the same form data is inserting  to Db , there is no problem . When about the updating , then problem is happening

Answer (score 0):

The reason is pretty simple...
if you create a new department you simply don't have an `department` Object.

So the pretty obvious solution would be,
instead of

```
<?php echo form_hidden('id',$department->id) ?>
```

you write

```
<?php 
if (isset($department) && $department->id > 0)
{
    echo form_hidden('id',$department->id);
}
?>
```

Comment: Sir, 1st error is gone . But when I am used the **$department**  at  with test_department_form.php on VIEW folder as 

`<input name="name"  type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="<?php echo display('department_name') ?>" value="<?php echo $department->name ?>">`

then the same message I am receiving like , 
`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: department
Filename: medical_diagnosis/test_department_form.php
Line Number: 27` 

Sir, please help  me to solve out. Thank you .

Comment: Sir , most of time also in other codes I am facing the same common problem like **Undefined variable** , its become a common problem to my code !!